# Checkbox input - onclick event - change href and checkbox image/value

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, href

I have this checkbox:

[image]

This is code for checkbox:

```
<input class="ace ace-switch"
       data-toggle="tooltip"
       data-placement="top"
       value="true"
       type="checkbox"
       id="checkBoxId"
       onclick="switch();" >
```

On click i want change href(url) and based on that url I hide/show some other element on page.

This is code for `onclick` event:

```
function switch() {
    location.href="../../app/?viewMode=<%= viewMode.equals("presentation")?"full":"presentation" %>"
}
```

On click href(url) is changed and elements is hide or show but switch image always stay off.

[image][image]

[image][image]

Why?

Comment: Because you reload the page it resets your switch, if you want to change url without reloading, use `history.pushState({}, document.title, "yourpage.html?viewMode=...")` instead of `location.href=...`

Comment: Is this Ruby? `<%= viewMode.equals ...`  If so, maybe tag the question with [tag:ruby]... I was going to offer a php solution but I don't think it would be appropriate

Comment: @i-- i change my function to this: 
history.pushState({}, document.title, "../../app/?viewMode=<%= viewMode.equals("presentation")?"full":"presentation" %>") -but dont work

Comment: @Hrvoje - by re-reading your question, it sounds that "cnexans" answer makes more sense. It is a matter of value true/false.

Answer (score 1):

It is always showing off because you're realoading the page. You just have to set the value according to the viewMode

```
<input class="ace ace-switch"
       data-toggle="tooltip"
       data-placement="top"
       value="<%= viewMode.equals("presentation")? "true":"false" %>"
       type="checkbox"
       id="checkBoxId"
       onclick="switch();" >
```

Comment: if i change to true and false then nothing happen because i use word "full" and "presentation" in code to hide/show some elements..

Comment: True/false refers to the value of the input

Comment: still because of reloading always stay off :(